# Eclipse git saying Connection Refused

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I am trying to clone a git repository in Eclipse stored at a server (connected to my system via LAN).

This is what I am filling in the `Import Projects From Git` dialog:

[image]

the repository is stored at: /home/sajat/git in the server.

However, when i click Next, I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: By default SSH port is 22 did you changed is that normal you write 80 ?

Comment: oops..i changed the port number to 22..but the error changed to `/git does not appear to be a git repository` whereas, I have created it to be a git repo.

Comment: How did you init the git repo on the server ?

Comment: `mkdir git`
`cd git`
`git init`

Comment: On the server you init the Git repo by doing git init --bare. Follow this : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems I see:

you are likely using the wrong port number, standard SSH is 22 and unless you have ssh listening on port 80 it will not work.

Also, you path is odd, `/git` is not the same as `/home/sajat/git`. Try using the long path.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this [how-to](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) if you're having trouble with a Git server create by your own